# Using K2 Page class suffix for Joomla page body

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I tried to add a page class suffix to a k2 item in Joomla, and the class added to the content area instead of the body.

How can I use this class and add it to the page body?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The page class suffix is utilized by the template. In order for the template to put the page class suffix in the body tag you would need something like this in the index.php file of your template -

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$params =  & $app->getParams('com_content');
$pageclass = $params->get('pageclass_sfx');
?>
<body class="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

Comment: Hi brent,
I tried this but it works only for Joomla articles / pages - not for K2 pages.

Comment: For more specific examples see the Joomla docs - http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Page_Class_Suffix_in_Template_Code